# Return id of resource, if i know name of resource

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

How i can return id of resource, if i know name of resource?

Something like this:

```
String mDrawableName = "myappicon";
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In MonoDroid, that code translates to something like:

```
 var resourceId = Resources.GetIdentifier(mDrawableName.ToLower(), "drawable", PackageName);
```

However, I personally don't use GetIdentifier as it's not recommended in Android - so I use Reflection instead:

```
 var resourceId = (int)typeof(Resource.Drawable).GetField(mDrawable).GetValue(null);
```

although that code should definitely have some try/catch error checking added for arbitrary strings!