# Resources.GetIdentifier() returning 0 for layout (Android)

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm attempting to get the int resource id for a layout resource by name, using Resources.GetIdentifier() of the Android API, but it returns 0. I'm using c#/monodroid/Xamarin, but regular java Android knowledge would apply too I suspect. Here's my code:

```
int resId = Resources.GetIdentifier(typeName, "layout", _activity.PackageName);
```

Where typeName = "FrmMain", and in my project I have the file "Resources/Layout/FrmMain.axml". Any ideas?

Answer (score 16):

This is old, but for everyone getting this problem, I think it is because the resource name should be in lower case, so:

```
int resId = Resources.GetIdentifier("FrmMain", "layout", _activity.PackageName);
```

does not work, but:

```
int resId = Resources.GetIdentifier("frmmain", nameof(Resource.Layout).ToLower(), _activity.PackageName);
```

should work

Comment: I am so mad that this is the problem I just spent an hour trying to solve :(

Comment: Or simply using `typeName.toLowerCase()` for the resource name.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why that's failing, but wouldn't something like `Resource.Layout.FrmMain` achieve what you're after?

---

**edit:**
According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13039419/1397117), you can (and should) use reflection to achieve what you're after, so I think you would try something like this:

```
var resourceId = (int)typeof(Resource.Layout).GetField(typeName).GetValue(null);
```

which does seem to work on my app and should get what you're after.

Comment: No because I need to look up the resource dynamically; sorry, forgot to mention that. "typeName" could be one of many things. "FrmMain" is just what I'm debugging with currently.

Comment: Thanks. This solution does work, and it's the one I had used myself as a work around, but I still don't understand why Resources.GetIdentifier() was not finding the resource; it seems that function is the more "correct" way of getting a resource id dynamically, rather than reflecting on the generated code in Resources. Nevertheless it works.

Comment: The code with reflection worked. I was trying to user the Resources.GetIdentifier inside a Fragment. May be thats why it was not working there.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this issue came up when I had to upgrade the target SDK due to google's new policy since November, 2018.

I had to display some strings according to the server response code (ex : api_res_001_suc), but it did not work on the upgraded version.

The overall version, about 22 as I recall, had to be changed to 27.

The cause of the issue seems to be the default translation stuff. When I put all the default translation for every string, it worked.

My code is,

```
getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "string", "packageName");
```

Comment: Can this be done within a class and not an activity or fragment?

Comment: Yes it should work if you have a proper context available.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a `ResourceHelper` class to handle this situation. Here is the code:

```
public static class ResourceHelper
{
    public static int FindId(string resourceId)
    {
        var type = typeof(Resource.Id);
        var field = type.GetField(resourceId);

        return (int)field.GetRawConstantValue();
    }

    public static int FindLayout(string layoutName)
    {
        var type = typeof(Resource.Layout);
        var field = type.GetField(layoutName);

        return (int)field.GetRawConstantValue();
    }

    public static int FindMenu(string menuName)
    {
        var type = typeof(Resource.Menu);
        var field = type.GetField(menuName);

        return (int)field.GetRawConstantValue();
    }
}
```

Actually I'm improving it because I need to use it from another Assembly and it's restricted to work in the same Assembly of the Droid App. I'm thinking about put a generic method (or an Extension one) to do this. Here is a draft of my idea:

```
public static int FindResource<T>(string resourceName)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var field = type.GetField(resourceName);

    return (int)field.GetRawConstantValue();
}
```

Hope it can help you.