# Find view Id that matches a string android

Tags: android, xamarin

How to get an ID name that matches a string in Android/Xamarin.
For example if I have `string="name"`; I want to find id in Resource.Designer that matches with that name for example:

```
 <ImageView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/name"/>
```

I tried with `getResources().getIdentifier` but it always returns null.

Comment: `getResources().getIdentifier` is a correct approach. Show how you do that, and we'll try to correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the ID of a string resource, you need to use `Resources.GetIdentifier()`:

**EX:**

```
var applicationNameId = Resources.GetIdentifier("ApplicationName", "string", this.PackageName);
```

This would get the Resource ID for the `ApplicationName` item in the `strings.xml` file.

```
<string name="ApplicationName">AppName</string>
```

In other words, I should be able to take the identifier this gives me and search through my `Resource.Designer.cs` for the same `int`.

If you wanted to get the identifier of a view `+id/` name, you might do the following instead:

**EX:**

`var buttonNameId = Resources.GetIdentifier("MyButton", "id", this.PackageName);`

Which would get the Resource ID for the `Button` with an Id of `MyButton`:

```
<Button  
    android:id="@+id/MyButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/Hello"
    />
```

However based on the documentation, this is discouraged as it's much slower than just getting resources by IDs rather than by Name.

> Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: For some reason this method doesn't work for me. I tried to apply it to ImageView as in example and it didn't work

Comment: Here is what I tried  var r1 = Resources.GetIdentifier("name", "int", this.PackageName); on Android 5.0

Comment: What are you retrieving? In my example it's a string resource. Thus you need to use string instead of int.

Comment: I am retrieving ImageView ID as in question

Comment: Updated to give an example of how you'd get it from a view as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var resourceId = (int)typeof(Resource.Id).GetField("name").GetValue(null);
```

Comment: Whoever down voted this question has no idea of what they are doing. If they did they would at least leave a comment why.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354312/resources-getidentifier-returning-0-for-layout-android/25475419#25475419 and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038895/return-id-of-resource-if-i-know-name-of-resource/13039419#13039419