# Getting a resource in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to do something very basic: Have an `ImageButton` load an image and an associated sound and have that sound play.  I thought it would be easy to do,  but I'm having two problems (although it probably is two symptoms of the same problem).

One, I don't see the images I added to the `Resources/drawable` folder show up in the `Resource.Drawable` class, all I see there is the default `Icon` from icon.png.  I added 20 images with a .jpg extension and set them to `AndroidResource` in properties.  They were numerically named, so I modified them to start with a letter (in case that was the problem), got rid of a dot in the name (in case that was the problem), and finally renamed them to .jpeg (in case that was it).  These don't seem to be reasons why they don't show up.

The `Resource.Designer.cs` works, though, because the two mp3s I added to the `Resources/raw` do show up in the class.

The other problem I have is that I can't tell how to load them programatically, so I can pass them to

```
imageButton.SetImageResource(imageId);
```

I tried

```
var imageId = this.Resources.GetIdentifier("DigiBord.Sunete:i00011", null, null);
```

which didn't work, but maybe the items were not in the project. So I tried again with an item I knew was in the project:

```
var imageId = this.Resources.GetIdentifier("DigiBord.Sunete:Icon", null, null);
```

which again yielded 0. There must be a way to load them without knowing the `int` id of the item ahead of time.

Comment: Have u tried `var imageId = this.Resources.GetIdentifier("Icon", null, null)` ?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038895/return-id-of-resource-if-i-know-name-of-resource post

Comment: ρяσѕρєя K, that stack overflow you found worked for me. I did it with reflection and it works. I couldn't find it by myself, thanks! Thanks to it, I found out that "i0011" doesn't work, but "Icon" does.  I don't know why I can't add those items to the project.